# delayed_job not able to connect to PG

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid, delayed-job, pg

I am using delayed_jobs for running some tasks in background. But sometimes it throws (PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server) error

```
ERROR -- : 2018-12-06T16:57:44+0100: [Worker] (id=5c0946e96d09fd6313fbdcf8) FAILED (1 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
ERROR -- : 2018-12-06T16:58:09+0100: [Worker] (id=5c0946e96d09fd6313fbdcf8) FAILED (2 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
ERROR -- : 2018-12-06T17:05:36+0100: [Worker] (id=5c0948cc6d09fd6316fbdd2b) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
ERROR -- : 2018-12-06T17:05:47+0100: [Worker] (id=5c0948cc6d09fd6316fbdd2b) FAILED (1 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
ERROR -- : 2018-12-06T17:06:12+0100: [Worker] (id=5c0948cc6d09fd6316fbdd2b) FAILED (2 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: no connection to the server
```

I am using:

1. Rails (5.1.4)
2. Ruby (2.3.4)
3. delayed_job (4.1.3)
4. delayed_job_mongoid (2.3.0)
5. mongoid (6.3.0)
6. pg (0.21.0)

We are migrating from mongoid to PG. Earlier when we were using only mongo then everything was working fine, but since we started migrating this issue started to happen.

we are using delayed_job with mongoid.

I have seen some of the posts on github but it didn't help.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/473

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your connection pool size?

Comment: Pool size is 50. @Oshanz